# Use shared preferences in checkbox to make checked for always when button is clicked

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I am using shared preferences to make the ckeckbox checked for always when button is clicked. But I'm getting errors, unknown type 'getChecked'. , code is givenbellow:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
boolean checkedSearch = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("checkedSearch", false);
Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);   
final CheckBox  checkBox1  = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
checkBox1.setChecked(checkedSearch ? true : false );
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
if(
checkBox1.getChecked()==false){
checkBox1.setChecked(true);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();  
editor.putBoolean("checkedSearch",true)
.commit();
}
```

Comment: inside onclick if statement   `if(
checkBox1.geChecked()==false)`   correct    it , it should be `checkBox1.isChecked()`

Comment: No, spelling has been mistake when I post on this stcovflw.

Comment: use `isChecked()`

Comment: Thanks, error is fixed but, now it's not working

Comment: Last question, now the checkbox remains checked ,, even when  it's  unchecked. Is there any unchecked() medhod?

Comment: to uncheck checkbox use   `checkBox1.setChecked(false);`

Answer (score 0):

```
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=this.getSharedPreferences("pref", 0);
```

you have missed = sign

Comment: What I didn't understand, please explain

Comment: use checkbox1.isChecked() instead of getChecked()